# Entity Framework - grouping by one column and selecting multiple columns

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework

I have this method for my API where I'm trying to filter out a user (`userId`) and group by `EventId`. Then I want to select three columns from the table: `name`, `eventId` and `UserId`.

This is my code but it's not working:

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{userId}")]
public IActionResult EventsMatchFiltered(int userId)
{
    var events = _dbContext.Events.Where(event1 => event1.UserId != userId)
       .GroupBy(g => new {g.EventId })
       .SelectMany(g => g.Select(h => new 
       {
           Name = h.Name, 
           h.EventId, 
           h.UserId 
       }));
    return Ok(events);
}
```

Comment: Not working in what way?

Comment: Does grouping by `EventId` make sense? I assume it's the unique PK of `Event`? That said,`GroupBy` followed by `SelectMany` almost certainly doesn't make much sense, because the groups are flattened immediately, making the query almost identical to a straight `Select`. And again, "it's not working" doesn't give us much to go by.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but to clarify EventId is not the Primary key, it's more of a cross reference. In layman's terms, what I have is an events table with the following columns: Id, Name, UserId, EventId. What I'm trying to do with my method is if I enter a userId as the parameter then it will filter out the userId and group by eventID. Then I want it to show the Name, UserId, and EventId. Based on some feedback, I've also tried this code but it returns a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Here's the latest code erroring
        public IActionResult EventsMatchFiltered(int userId)
        {
            var events = _dbContext.Events
                .Where(event1 => event1.UserId != userId)
                .GroupBy(g => g.EventId)
                .Select(g => new Event
                {
                    EventId = g.Key,
                    Events = g.Select(e => new Event
                    {
                        Name = e.Name,
                        UserId = e.UserId
                    })

                });    
            return Ok(events);
        }

Comment: One day you'll have to reveal which exception message you get. Not "500" etc. The exception raised by the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, events would be an `IQueryable` rather than a materialized collection. Second, it would be an anonymous type rather than a proper DTO/ViewModel serializable class. Thirdly, you are grouping by an EventId, but then not "selecting" anything based on that grouping. EventId sounds like the Primary Key of the Event you are supposedly grouping.. Are you sure you don't actually mean to Group by User??

Normally for something like a Grouped result you would have a view model something like:

```
[Serializable]
public class UserEventSummaryViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EventSummaryViewModel> Events { get; set; } = new List<EventSummaryViewModel>();
}

[Serializable]
public class EventSummaryViewModel
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then to query and fill:

```
var otherUserEvents = _dbContext.Events
   .Where(e => e.UserId != userId)
   .GroupBy(g => g.UserId )
   .Select(g => new UserEventSummaryViewModel
   { 
       UserId == g.Key,
       Events = g.Select(e => new EventSummaryViewModel
       {
           EventId = e.EventId,
           Name = e.Name
       }).ToList()
   }).ToList();
```

This would provide a structure of events grouped by each of the other Users. If you want UserId and UserName then add the UserName property to the UserEventSummary view model and in the GroupBy clause:

```
.GroupBy(g => new { g.UserId, g.Name } )
```

and populate these in the viewmodel with:

```
UserId == g.Key.UserId,
UserName = g.Key.Name,
```

Comment: It is not necessary to have concrete types (view models as you've called them here) anonymous types will work fine in most cases. You want to avoid the inner `.ToList()`, and the outer one especially it to this is part of a larger query that you want to defer. Like in scenarios with `[EnableQuery]`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but to clarify EventId is not the Primary key, it's more of a cross reference. In layman's terms, what I have is an events table with the following columns: Id, Name, UserId, EventId. What I'm trying to do with my method is if I enter a userId as the parameter then it will filter out the userId and group by eventID. Then I want it to show the Name, UserId, and EventId. Based on some feedback, I've also tried this code but it returns a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Here's the latest code erroring public IActionResult EventsMatchFiltered(int userId) { var events = _dbContext.Events .Where(event1 => event1.UserId != userId) .GroupBy(g => g.EventId) .Select(g => new Event { EventId = g.Key, Events = g.Select(e => new Event { Name = e.Name, UserId = e.UserId }) }); return Ok(events); }

Comment: Ok, that makes a bit more sense, though confusing to have an EventId inside a table/entity Event that isn't the PK. :) A 500 error is a generic "catch all" response from the server to avoid exposing details about the inner-workings. You'll need to run your code with a debugger and either catch the exception to inspect and step through to see where it is failing. If it's not even getting into your method (no breakpoint hit) then there is an issue with the parameter/signature. How are you calling this method? Via Ajax?